# Tangent spheres tangent to vertices of a triangle

Tags: geometry, 3d

Three spheres are tangent to a plane at the vertices of a triangle and are tangent to each other.
Find the radii of these spheres if the sides of the triangle are 6, 8, and 10.

My go at it: We can turn this into a 2d geo problem. We let the radii's be x,y, and z. Then x+z = 6, z+y = 8 and x+y = 10. Solving the system of equations, we get that x,y,z = 4,6,2.

However my answers did not match the answer key and I do not where I went wrong. Can anybody help? thanks.

Comment: If the plane is x-y plane, 6,8,10 distances are parallel to this plane, but distance between centers are not parallel to this plane.

Comment: yea i just realized that. Any hints on how to go about this problem then?

Comment: Hint : 6,8,10 is projection of triangle formed by joining centers.

Comment: now im getting that xy =9 yz = 16 xz =25 but how do i get the x,y, and z?

Comment: Correct. Take product to find xyz.

Comment: :wallbash: thank you!

Comment: Are the radii $\frac{60}{25}$, $\frac{60}{16}$ and $\frac{60}{9}$? Just wanted to check my results

Comment: @Patricio yes nice job!